# Efficient way to find results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Forgive me for being a complete beginner. I'm trying to understand how this code works, focusing on the `where` clause specifically. I'm trying understand how using a `> 'a'` doesn't fall over on a `varchar` column when it has a specific value in the column itself?

```
select        
    t.ID,
    t.[Balance] as Balance,
    a.pmt as MinDue,
    'epf' as EPF,
    t.Column1 
from          
    id_table t
left join 
    id_daily_link a on a.ID = t.ID and a.id_suf = 0
where         
    t.Column1 > 'a'
    and t.[Suf] = 0
```

Results:

```
ID   Balance    Mindue   EPF    Column1 
---------------------------------------
1      65.44    122.00   epf    BNP3
2     336.20     21.59   epf    BNP3
3    8761         5.00   epf    BNP3
4      69.47      0.00   epf    BNP3
5      33.76      6.00   epf    BNP3
6      81.6      37.26   epf    BNP3
7     453.94      0.00   epf    BNP3
8     627.36     16.76   epf    BNP3
9       5.50     23.00   epf    BNP3
10    266.00    255.00   epf    BNP3
```

Comment: Start with [`>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/greater-than-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), then, since you didn't provide DDL, [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and move along to [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15) and you'll be on your way. You can also fiddle about with `select case when 'Ä' > then 'ä' then 'yes' else 'no' end;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators such as `>` and `<` work fine on strings.  No problem at all.

The default ordering is basically "dictionary" ordering.  Of course, the details do get complicated when you realize that there are many different languages, dictionaries, and character sets in the world.  For such details, you can start by learning about [collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15).

But the basic idea of saying that `'a' < 'b'` is very sensible and allowed in SQL and most programming languages.

Comment: Ah so does that mean SQL can read it as an integer value? Like if "a" = 1, "b" = 2 etc.? For example Column1, the values in there begin with "E", SQL would categorise that as a higher value than "a"?

Comment: @GrahamDrew: no - T-SQL interprets this as characters and has a dictionary of the ordering of characters - so it knows that `a` becomes before `b` and thus the comparison operator works just fine - no conversions to `int` involved....

Comment: @marc_s Ah right, I see now. Thank you, this makes sense now!!

Comment: @GrahamDrew . . . The statement `"a" = 1` will try to convert the column `a` to an integer.  This will result in a compile-time error if `a` is not a column (SQL uses single quotes for strings).  It will result in a run-time error if `a` has values that cannot be converted to ints.